# numeric-style citation labels and print contents of "abstract" field

Tags: bibtex

I am doing this in LaTeX text:

```
study, Hansen (1996)\cite{hansen1996water}
```

and get the following in output file:

> Hansen (1996)[hansen1996water]

I need numbers not citation tags to show. I know how to solve the problem if I do not need the abstract in the references.

I simply use the following in the main file: `\bibliographystyle{abstract} \bibliography{temp}`. The file `temp.bib` includes the references. In the body file I cite as above: i.e `Hansen (1996)\cite{hansen1996water}`

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document} 
\bibliographystyle{abstract} 
\bibliography{temp}% The bib file name. 
\begin{section} 
...Talatala 2008\cite{talatala2008} 
\end{section} 
\end{document}
```

The contents of `temp.bib`:

```
@article{talatala2008,  
   title={The effect of tap water perception on the consumption of bottled water}, 
   author={Talatala, Susan}, 
   journal={Public Perceptions of Tap Water}, 
   year={2008}, 
   abstract={Over the past 30 years, drinking water ...bottled water and tap water one consumes.} 
}
```

Comment: You mention `biblatex`: have you run LaTeX, then Biber (or BibTeX if appropriate) and then LaTeX again? If you are using `biblatex` there are dedicated commands for author-year type citations.

Comment: If you are really using biblatex you shouldn't use `\bibliographystyle`.

Comment: I think what you mean is that you want a citation style like [1], [2], etc. This is specified by the `\bibliographystyle`, for example `\bibliographystyle{abbrv}` (cf. [http://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibtex_bibliography_styles]).

Comment: I have explained my situation above. I need the abstracts to be included in the references but do not abbreviations of names but numbers in the main text.

Comment: I'm not sure if you mean the same thing by abstract as I do. Are you really referring to the short summary of a paper or are you talking about the inline-citation? Can you give us a minimal working example containing your preamble?

Comment: @henning -- There's a bibliography style called `abstract` that prints, you guessed it, the contents of any `abstract` fields that may be present in a bibliographic entry.

Comment: Exactly as you see from Answer 1 below

Comment: See also [Bibliography Style with abstract and numbered references](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/249336/35864)

Answer (score 1):

(Too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer.)

I gather you wish to use the `abstract` bibliography style since it's set to print the contents of any `abstract` fields (as well as incidentally, `keyword` and `comment` fields) that may be present in the bib entries. However, as you've discovered, the `abstract` bibliography style generates citaton call-out labels of the form `[author:year]`, rather than numeric-style labels. This setting seems to be hard-wired into the style file. I checked whether loading the `natbib` package with the option `numbers` might help produce numeric citation call-outs, but no luck.

Rather than hack the file `abstract.bst` to produce numeric labels, you may be better off choosing an existing style file that (a) generates numeric-style citation call-outs and (b) formats the bib entries to your liking, and to modify that style file to add routines that print out the contents of any `abstract` fields. If that's how you wish to proceed, it may be best if you post a new query, in which you state which bibliography style you'd like to start out with and ask how it should be modified to print out the contents of any `abstract` fields.

Comment: Thanks, Mico, can you elaborate more on this?

Comment: @BassamAwad - As I said, in order to achieve your objective, i.e., to get a bibliography style that generates numeric-style citation call-outs *and* typesets the contents of the `abstract` fields of bibliographic entries, you may be better off *not* modifying the existing `abstract.bst` file but, instead, modifying an existing style file that (a) generates numeric labels and formats all fields (except the `abstract` field) exactly to your liking. Since I don't know so far how the other fields are supposed to be formatted, I suggested you post a new query to this site.

Answer (score 0):

It's really difficult to help you without a MWE. However, I recommend you use [BibLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13509/biblatex-for-idiots) (with Biber as backend) instead of BibTex. BibLaTeX provides the citation style `numeric`, which produces numeric citations, and the bibliography style `reading`, which prints out an abstract.

Sorry, but I don't have time right now to try out the code snippets below, but I guess your preamble should contain something like:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,
            citestyle=numeric,
            bibliographystyle=reading
           ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib} % path to your bib file.
```

Or, if you don't like the reading style, try:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,
            style=numeric,
            abstract=true
           ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib} % path to your bib file.
```

Have a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13509/biblatex-for-idiots) to learn how to use BibLaTeX in conjunction with Biber.

Comment: Can you elaborate more henning?

Comment: I've added examples but can't do much more right now.

Comment: Thanks. I have inserted the package and getting the error:  Package keyval error: abstract undefined

Comment: I can confirm the second one doesn't work - it seems that abstract= is only an option for the reading style. Pity - I'd found this having had the same question!