# Bibliography Style with abstract and numbered references

Tags: biblatex

How to get a bibliography style that generates numeric-style citation call-outs and typesets the contents of the abstract fields of bibliographic entries?

Comment: Please give an MWE with one bib entry containing that abstract field. You should also write two sample lines: 1. how you are going to cite and 2. how you want the result to look like. Thank you.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi What do you mean by MWE?

Comment: A minimal working example. Please see here: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228

Comment: How about using `style=numeric` and just adding `\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{\printfield{abstract}\finentry}` to your preamble?

Comment: @moewe, thanks. Can I refer you to question 249312? That includes what i did in a MWE?

Comment: The piece of code you posted there does not use `biblatex`, but your question is tagged with `biblatex`. Some answers mention it though, are you planning on using `biblatex` and if so what style are you planning on using: In other words If you were to start writing a new document now with `biblatex` what would it look like, post that as MWE, please.

Comment: @moewe, thanks again. I use latex with no changes in the document code as you saw it. I really do not know what matters for biblatex or else. My only only is be able to include the abstracts of references in the reference list and refer to them as numbers in the paper body.

Comment: Well, if you did not change the code in the question *you are not using `biblatex`*. If you do use `biblatex` as suggested in the answers, please try my suggestion from above. If you don't want to use `biblatex`, retag the question so people don't get confused.

Comment: @moewe I would simply assume `biblatex` and write an answer, might be useful for others. Would you do that?

Comment: @Johannes_B I'll do that then ...

Answer (score 11):

You seem to want a [`numeric`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/30-style-numeric.pdf) style, `biblatex` offers some variations on your classical version, namely [`numeric-comp`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/31-style-numeric-comp.pdf) and [`numeric-verb`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/).

---

The `abstract` field is by default not included in the bibliography output, but we can easily add it using

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{abstract}{\par\small#1}
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{\printfield{abstract}\finentry}
```

Where the first line takes care of a nice formatting.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{abstract}{\par\small#1}
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{\printfield{abstract}\finentry}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,kastenholz}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wonder why the standard styles don't use the abstract field? ;-)  Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 5):

I know it's fairly late now. I just want to tack on an 'improvement' to @moewe 's answer. This way nothing is done if the abstract field is undefined, say for a dictionary entry or something. It also puts a period (`\finentrypunct`) at the end of the previous line before printing the abstract.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{abstract}{\par\small\textbf{Abstract}: #1}
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
   \iffieldundef{abstract}
      {%
         \finentry
      }
      {%
         \finentrypunct\printfield{abstract}\finentry
      }
   }
```

I use something like the above, including a new toggle coupled with `\newcommand` to have the ability to selectivity to turn abstracts on for a particular bibliography, say personal publications in a thesis as an example, or turn it on globally at the package load with `printabstract=true`.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\printabstractstrue{\settoggle{bbx:printabstract}{true}}
\newcommand\printabstractfalse{\settoggle{bbx:printabstract}{false}}
\makeatother

\newtoggle{bbx:printabstract}
\DeclareBibliographyOption{printabstract}[true]{%
   \settoggle{bbx:printabstract}{#1}%
   }

\DeclareFieldFormat{abstract}{\par\small\textbf{Abstract}: #1}
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
   \iffieldundef{abstract}
      {%iffieldFALSE
         \finentry
      }
      {%iffieldTRUE
         \iftoggle{bbx:printabstract}
            {%iftoggleTRUE
               \finentrypunct\printfield{abstract}\finentry
            }
            {%iftoggleFALSE
            \finentry
            }
      }
   }
```

Comment: You can additionally make `printabstract` an entry option (`\DeclareEntryOption`). The logic in `finentry` can be shortened using `\ifboolexpr{ not test {\iffieldundef{abstract}} and togl {bbx:printabstract} }` (or something along those lines, I didn't test it)